# MassTransit 8 upgrade: usage of message encryption

Tags: masstransit

Upgrading from MassTransit 7.3 to 8 encountered the following problem:

In version 7.3.1.0 the MassTransit package has means to serialize messages with encryption:

```
void UseEncryption(this IBusFactoryConfigurator configurator, ISecureKeyProvider keyProvider)
```

However in 8.0.7 this functionality has been moved to the package MassTransit.Newtonsoft.

Since starting from version 8 MassTransit uses by default `System.Text.Json` we would like to use that serializer. But I haven't found a way to use message encryption other than using  "MassTransit.Newtonsoft". Is message encryption in "MassTransit.Newtonsoft" is supposed to be used only with "Newtonsoft" serialization? Is there any way to use message encryption with the default `System.Text.Json` serialization?

We are using Azure Service Bus as a broker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encryption layer for MassTransit v8 serialization has not be written yet. The only available option is the legacy Newtonsoft one you were already using.